# 2 hard drives sharing the Documents / My Documents folder. How to unmerge?

Tags: windows-7

I'm having an interesting issue where after upgrading to Windows 7 (C:), my older Hard Drive that I've plugged in as a secondary drive (E:) now thinks that the "Documents" folder on C:, is the same folder as the My Documents folder on E:.

The contents of Documents, will be the same in E:'s My Documents. Thus, a mirror / shared folder of sorts.

I know they're separate folders entirely, and I do believe I have files on the unique one in E:. However, E: displays C:'s contents.

If I delete a file in Documents on C:, the document will be removed on E:, and vise versa.

How do I go about fixing this? They're suppose to be 2 separate, unique folders, with unique content. Yet, E: thinks the folder contains all the stuff from C:.

Edit: I forgot to point out this is only noticible when I try to search the drive. If I navigate to the full path on E:, it displays the contents. However, the rest of Windows (Apps, etc) can't access what's on E: and treat it as if it's in C:.

Comment: 1) Are you using some confusing thing called 'libraries'?  2) Are the files different if you browse to them using the full path? (e.g. start, run, `c:` ENTER, users, yourusername, ...)

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to be more specific. The files are correct if I browse to them correctly using the full path. `E:\users\name\documents` yields the correct contents.

However, all applications as well as windows search assume the contents of it shares the contents of what's in Documents. And no, I'm not confusing the the "Libraries" but Windows sure is.

Sorry for not being clearer.

Essentially, programs & search treat the contents of `E:` as if it's part of the Libraries in `C:`.